# Disable CTRL + A shortcut in KeePass

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keepass

How do I disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut in KeePass?

This is "ą" in Polish and I use it very often. I've dug into options and found nothing. It's annoying not being able to type normally with KeePass open.

Comment: The even more annoying thing about alt-a is, it's default behavior is copy-paste and confirm (enter) the currently selected login and password to whatever text-field the cursor might be in. So, for instance, while chatting with KeePass on you end up sharing your passwords with your chat-mates. Totally annoying. Thank you for asking this.

Comment: why do you talk about `ctrl+A` but then answer about `Alt+A`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cornelius'answer from Aug 18 '10 is almost two years old.

Here is the solution for KeePass 2.21.

Go to Tools/Options/Integration/System-wide hot keys/Global auto-type and clear the shortcut already written there (*Ctrl, Alt + A*); it will change to *None*. There you have it!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To change <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut go to:

> Tools > Options > Advanced > Auto-type (button at the bottom)

and change key combination here.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Remaping "ą" is obviously not a solution. Go to Tools > Options, then Advanced tab and click Auto-Type button. You may disable it or change.

Generally it is bad idea to register as a *global* shortcut any combination of Ctrl+Alt.

Answer (score 0):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) will be able to help you remap the "ą" to another key combination that won't interfere with KeePass.